# ClickSend SMS API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use this API but falling at the first hurdle. The online chat person does not know and has left it that someone will email me.
I am simply trying to implement the example before proceeding as given at https://developers.clicksend.com/docs/rest/v3/?php#reseller-transfer-credit

So I have used composer to get the package:

composer require clicksend/clicksend-php;

I wish to use it within a Laravel class (BaseComms) so have implemented the method

```
  public static function sms_send($to, $msgbody) {
    $smsuname = Config("app.api_sms_username");
    $smspword = Config("app.api_sms_username");
    $config = ClickSend\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setUsername($smsuname)->setPassword($smspword);
    $apiInstance = new ClickSend\Api\SMSApi(new GuzzleHttp\Client(), $config);
    $msg = new \ClickSend\Model\SmsMessage();
    $msg->setBody("test body");
    $msg->setTo("********");
    $msg->setSource("sdk");
    $sms_messages = new \ClickSend\Model\SmsMessageCollection();
    $sms_messages->setMessages([$msg]);
    try {
      $result = $apiInstance->smsSendPost($sms_messages);
      print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Exception when calling SMSApi->smsSendPost: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
```

To be called with

```
BaseComms::send_sms(0123456789,"test");
```

However I get **Class '\ClickSend\Configuration'** not found error. I know I need to specify the namespace to use but not sure what this is, eg like

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

As per suggestion I have changed this line to

```
$config = \ClickSend\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setUsername($smsuname)->setPassword($smspword);
```

however I now get error

Class 'ClickSend\Configuration' not found

Update today, ClickSend are blaming composer (which I have reinstalled under their direction to give exactly the same error).
So I have attempted to use CURL as per their API.

```
  public static function sms_send($to, $msgbody) {
    $smsapiuname = Config("app.api_sms_username");
    $smsapikey = Config("app.api_sms_key");
    $sms = [
    "messages" => [
        "to" => "0736*****a mobile number ****",
        "source" => "sdk",
        "body" => "test message"
    ]
    ];
    $authheader = ['Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$smsapiuname:$smsapikey")];
    CURL::send("https://rest.clicksend.com/v3/sms/send", $sms, $authheader);
  }
```

and then in the CURL class

```
  public static function send($url, $curldata, $httpheader = null) {
    $curlinstance = curl_init();
    $datastring = http_build_query($curldata);
    if ($httpheader) {
      curl_setopt($curlinstance, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheader);
    }
    curl_setopt($curlinstance, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlinstance, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curlinstance, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlinstance, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastring);
    $result = curl_exec($curlinstance);
  }
```

however the value of $result is

```
{"http_code":400,"response_code":"BAD_REQUEST","response_msg":"The messages array is empty.","data":null}
```

Comment: Try `\ClickSend\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration(...)....`.

Comment: no still not found

Comment: Is it _exactly_ the same error?

Comment: no, have updated question

Answer (score 1):

I have got this working in laravel with the following:
add the following 'use'at the top of the controller

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use ClickSend\Configuration;
    use ClickSend\Api\SMSApi;
```

then the following (as an example) in your function:

```
    $config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()
          ->setUsername('USERNAME')
          ->setPassword('API_KEY');

    $apiInstance = new SMSApi(new Client(),$config);
    $q = "sms/inbound"; // string | Your keyword or query.
    $page = 1; // int | Page number
    $limit = 10; // int | Number of records per page

    try {
        $result = $apiInstance->smsInboundGet($q, $page, $limit);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling SMSApi->smsInboundGet: ', $e->getMessage(),    PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing via composer, I added `use ClickSend;` at the top of my controller.

I also adjusted `new GuzzleHttp\Client()` calls to `new \GuzzleHttp\Client()` (adding a '\' at the front)

That's all I had to do to get it working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor ClickSend appears to have very lame support and none functional code and examples.

So I investigated Twilio (other providers are available !!).

Cheaper and the support is actually exemplary.
The support guide actually got what I wanted as a demo in about 10 minutes exactly as the example code stated.

```
composer require twilio/sdk;
```

then

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/php#install-php-and-the-twilio-php-helper-library

Absolutely nothing wrong with composer as ClickSend attempted as an excuse.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because my import path for the `/vendor` was wrong (`__DIR__` wasn't correct for me).

In my case, it was actually

```php
require_once('../../../vendor/autoload.php');
```